Need a way to make phone calls using Facetime on Mac but without opening Facetime or Contacts app…
As per the title I'd like some way to type in a phone number to say a widget or something and it to instigate a Facetime call using my iPhone.
Facetime is already all set up to use the phone to make calls and does work fine but the problem I have is that every time I open up the Facetime app and make a call the camera I am using which is connected to my computer (Insta360Link) has it's resolution and rotation reset and I'm using the camera to record into OBS but have to keep resetting the rotation in the Insta360Link application every time which is very annoying.
So I was wondering if anyone knew of a widget or tiny app or maybe a menu bar app which you can just type a phone number into and it starts a phone call using Facetime but without actually opening up the Facetime app?

Just wondering why my question was edited and the last part taken out? Thanks.

Sure. Check out the Shortcuts app, making a custom widget for people you want to call and adding it to your Control Center or as a widget to your Home Screen .
-https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/run-shortcuts-from-the-home-screen-widget-apd029b36d05/ios
Step one, make and test a specific contact to call. You can add a contact to a widget and select the action. (This might even be covered in the tips app). Then you can expand the shortcut to pop up a field in which you could type or past a number to call.

Thank you! I've just created a shortcut which asks for input (the phone number) and then dials the number for you. I'm not sure why but sometimes it opens Facetime after the call has been made and sometimes doesn't which is really odd however I've gotten around the camera problem by just choosing a non-existent camera in the Facetime settings and now it doesn't mess with my camera at all and I'm free to record in OBS without any troubles. Thank you for the idea though, very much appreciated.
